# Proof of n-th root of unity modulo q?

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, roots

How can I prove the following?

There exists an integer $a$ other than 1 such that $a^n = 1 \mod q$ when $q = 1 \mod n$.

- $q$: either a prime or an arbitrary integer.
- $n$: even integer

If $q$ is a prime, yes we can prove that using Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is $q$ supposed to be prime?

Comment: @B.Goddard Yes! I will edit  the question

Comment: Then apply Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: Ah, it's so easy! What happens if $q$ is not a prime?

Comment: How about $a=1$?

Comment: It gets messier.  You could probably make a similar problem based on Euler's Theorem.

Comment: Or, if $a=1$ is too easy, since $n$ is now even you could take $a=-1$.

Comment: Please ignore $a=1$ since it's too easy

Comment: $a=q+1$, or $a = 2^{\frac{\phi(q)}{\gcd (n, \phi(q))}}$